# Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to perform an AWS upload on iOS. I'm looping through an array of `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest` objects and uploading a lot of images (1000+) of varying size to an S3 bucket. Using:

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

        [[transferManager upload:request] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                           withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
```

Once I get to about the 700th image the upload progress starts get really slow and then I start receiving these errors on every other subsequent image upload:

```
2015-03-27 11:07:30.238 crafted[4979:1414229] Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSGeneralErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSGeneralErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x1709b5b60 {SignatureProvided=f8c21dd55c323378b05c660a5f27255a2aecbd6eee1f2ca0c5fb0460136dde30, RequestId=DB37767F9C1AFD7E, StringToSign=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
20150327T160658Z
20150327/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request
1e63d8ac434ee08f333a4f59c52fc3565e5b451cca9c7f1a946e209fb72f24c5
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
11b7db18ee4cbdedc46907daa5e99688b2be72da3a943ac0354a9405b7c59f19, Code=SignatureDoesNotMatch, HostId=0V4bjdhjCG/wt/NAlsgr1K7DV6QkUdYOlwjFRfmBI/swFesufXVi19PTgacwOBt1, StringToSignBytes=41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44 0a 32 30 31 35 30 33 32 37 54 31 36 30 36 35 38 5a 0a 32 30 31 35 30 33 32 37 2f 75 73 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 31 65 36 33 64 38 61 63 34 33 34 65 65 30 38 66 33 33 33 61 34 66 35 39 63 35 32 66 63 33 35 36 35 65 35 62 34 35 31 63 63 61 39 63 37 66 31 61 39 34 36 65 32 30 39 66 62 37 32 66 32 34 63 35 0a 65 33 62 30 63 34 34 32 39 38 66 63 31 63 31 34 39 61 66 62 66 34 63 38 39 39 36 66 62 39 32 34 32 37 61 65 34 31 65 34 36 34 39 62 39 33 34 63 61 34 39 35 39 39 31 62 37 38 35 32 62 38 35 35 0a 31 31 62 37 64 62 31 38 65 65 34 63 62 64 65 64 63 34 36 39 30 37 64 61 61 35 65 39 39 36 38 38 62 32 62 65 37 32 64 61 33 61 39 34 33 61 63 30 33 35 34 61 39 34 30 35 62 37 63 35 39 66 31 39, 

AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJCSIGUTUKG2HSYCA, 
Message=The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.}
```

**"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."**

I have no idea why this is happening and I am unable to find a similar Q/A on this issue.

Edit:
I am using Cognito Identity pool to authenticate and provide anonymous access to the s3 bucket for puts only.

Edit 2: Code Per Yosuke's request (I simply build out an array of requests objects then loop through the array and upload each request):

```
- (void)performS3UploadWithRequest:(NSMutableArray *)requests
{
    for (AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest  *request in requests) {

        AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [[transferManager upload:request] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                           withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                                if (task.error) {
                                                                   if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                                       switch (task.error.code) {
                                                                           case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                           case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                               break;

                                                                           default:
                                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                               break;

                                                                       }
                                                                   } else {
                                                                       // Unknown error.
                                                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                   }
                                                               }

                                                               if (task.result) {
                                                                   AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;

                                                                   // The file uploaded successfully.
                                                                   NSLog(@"%@", uploadOutput);
                                                                   [weakSelf countUploadProgress];
                                                               }
                                                               return nil;
                                                           }];
    }
}

- (AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *)createUploadRequestWithDestinationBucket:(NSString *)destBucket Key:(NSString *)key Body:(NSURL *)body
{
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = destBucket;
    uploadRequest.key = key;
    uploadRequest.body = body;
    uploadRequest.contentType = @"binary/octet-stream";

    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = ^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (totalBytesExpectedToSend > 0) {
                NSLog(@"%f", (float)((double) totalBytesSent / totalBytesExpectedToSend));
            }
        });
    };

    return uploadRequest;
}
```

Comment: Did you already checked for leading or trailing space on your secret access key? Do you get the error when you loop through less images as well?

Comment: I failed to mention I am using Cognito Identity pool to authenticate and provide anonymous access to the s3 bucket for puts only.

Comment: That stringtosign looks weird, why does it trail with -payload?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Can you provide a complete code snippet to reproduce the issue? Also, can you turn on the [debug logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#logging) and post the logs?

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda 
See edit above for code I am using.
AWS SDK (2.1.0) 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Colbize/d2a38b1d0ccf480a3912/raw/gistfile1.txt

Comment: You may be overflowing the queue. Can you try calling the uploads [in sequence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/bftask.html#in-sequence)? Also, instead of using `mainThreadExecutor` and executing the entire block on the main thread, running only `[weakSelf countUploadProgress];` on the main thread may help performance issue.

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda I was thinking that might be the issue as well..  I will make these changes and get back to you sometime next week.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yosuke I found a [solution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/awstask.html#in-sequence) which was to run the for loop sequentially.  It is a bit slower but there are no issues and still pretty quick even with 1000+ photo upload.

```
- (void)performS3UploadWithRequest:(NSMutableArray *)requests
{
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

    BFTask *task = [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    for (AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest  *request in requests) {
        task = [task continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            return [[transferManager upload:request] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                                withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                                    if (task.error) {
                                                                        if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                                            switch (task.error.code) {
                                                                                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                                    break;

                                                                                default:
                                                                                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                                    break;

                                                                            }
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            // Unknown error.
                                                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }

                                                                    if (task.result) {
                                                                        AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                                        [weakSelf countUploadProgress];

                                                                        // The file uploaded successfully.
                                                                        NSLog(@"%@", uploadOutput);
                                                                    }
                                                                    return nil;
                                                                }];

        }];

        [task continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            return nil;
        }];
    }

}
```